# Read string from file and pass to command, keeping dollar sign intact

Tags: bash, shell-script, npm

Consider a string stored in a file, which I need to read and pass to a Node script via NPM. But the string in the file contains a `$`, and is being interpreted as a variable and is replaced before being passed to the command.

Note: the reason the string is stored in a file is because it is not something that should appear in the history file.

```bsh
# store and then read the variable
echo 'my$tring' > x
export X=`cat x`

./do-it -x $X
```

`./do-it` looks like:

```bsh
echo $@
npm start -- $@
```

And the `start` script in `package.json` looks like:

```bsh
node ./dist/index.js
```

---

If I store "my$tring" in the file `x`, and output things along the way, it will look like this:

```bsh
./do-it -x $X

-x my$tring                              # Result of echo $@ shows includes the $ -- good

> start                                  # Node script "start"
> node ./dist/index.js "-x" "my$tring"   # Command being executed by NPM (bad)

my                                       # Result of console.log() with the 2nd arg
```

In the above, notice how `node ./dist/index.js "-x" "my$tring"` is double-quoting the arguments, thereby consuming the `$tring` portion of the 2nd argument. **This is what I need to fix**, as it causes the final argument sent to `index.js` to be just `my`.

Comment: quote your variables and it will be fine --> `./do-it -x "$X"` and `npm start -- "$@"`

Comment: you should use `"$X"` and `"$@"`, but that's not your problem here. It looks to `npm` wants to pass that through the shell, which means the dollar sign is special. Try to see if it supports escaping the dollar or running the command directly

Comment: @pLumo, quoting in the shell parts would affect word splitting and globbing, but there isn't anything to split (`$@` will still produce multiple args, of course). E.g. `foo='my$string'; printf "%s\n" $foo` prints `my$string`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @pLumo `./do-it -x "$X"` and `npm start -- "$@"` has the same result, it has no effect in this case.

Comment: Yes, like @ikkachu said, I guess it's something in your `npm` script that produces the issue.

Comment: @pLumo / @ikkachu -- I'll add the quotes around `$@` for good measure.

Comment: I agree, because NPM is adding double-quotes around each arg, causing them to be interpreted. I'll do some more research there.